# Update order fields with discount 5% for customers with over 5 years using after insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I am failing to create an AFTER INSERT trigger that will
UPDATE A table with discounts, be it 5% or 10% discount,
to my Orders table. At the same time, I need to update the
Orders table with people that qualify for the discount whereby
they are 5years or more since registration with us.
So I need the discount AND Total_price to Update After INSERT'ing
into the Orders table for the purchases they made with a new
Total_Price AFTER the discount has been
calculated (Total_Price=Total_Price - (Total_Price*0.05)).

These are Two sample tables I have below:

Customer Table

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(4)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reg_date | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

Customer(ID, Name, Reg_Date, Address, City)

Orders Table

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Onumber        | int(4)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Product        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Quantity       | int(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Price          | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Total_Price    | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id             | int(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ODate          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Discount       | varchar(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| discount_price | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Orders(O_Number, Product, Quantity, Price, Total_Price, ID references Customer(ID), Date, Discount)

So when I insert values into the Orders table I need the trigger to CHECK if The ID found in Orders belongs to a Customer who has registered 5 or more years ago, and IF so the trigger should UPDATE their Total_Price With a discounted price and UPDATE the Discount Field with the Discount they are receiving. And Of course if the Customer is not registered more then 5 years ago, NOTHING should happen.

I have tried a series of triggers I'm trying to create to make this possible but again and again nothing I come up with works.

Below are what I have tried And the errors I received ENJOY!!:

```
> Create trigger discount_ai
> AFTER insert
> ON Orders
> Begin
> UPDATE ORDERS
> SET Customer.id=Orders.id;
> Discount = 5;
> Discount_Price = Total_Price * 0.05;
> WHERE Customer.id = Orders.id && reg_date <= "2016-01-01";
> END$
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'Begin UPDATE ORDERS
```

```
> Create trigger Discount_Ai
> after insert
> on orders
> for each row
> Begin
> update orders
> set customer.id=orders.id
> discount = 5,
> discount_price = total_price * 5/100
> where customer.id = orders.id and reg_date <="2017-01-01";
> end$
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'discount = 5,
> discount_price = total_price * 5/100
> where customer.id = orders.id' at line 8
```

```
> create trigger Discount_ai AFTER Insert On Order for each row
> BEGIN
> IF Customer reg_date <= 2017-01-01 THEN Update Orders where Orders.Total_Price = Orders.Total_Price - (Orders.Total_Price * 5%) 
AND Set Orders.Discount=5% where Orders.id=new.id;
> End IF
> END$
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'Order for each row 
> BEGIN
```

```
> create trigger discount_ai after insert on orders for each row
> Begin
> update orders
> set customer.id = orders.id
> discount= 5
> discount = Total_Price *5/100
> where customer.id = orders.id and reg_date <="2017-01-01";
> end$
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'discount= 5
> discount = Total_Price *5/100 
> where customer.id = orders.id and reg_' at line 5
```

```
> Create trigger Discount_ai
> AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
> FOR EACH ROW
> UPDATE Orders
> IF Customer.reg_date <= "2016-01-01" THEN
> SET Orders.Total_Price = Orders.Total_price - (Orders.Total_Price * 0.05) && Discount_Price = 5;
> WHERE Orders.id=customer.id;
> END$
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'IF Customer.reg_date <= "2016-01-01" THEN
> SET Orders.Total_Price = Orders.Total_' at line 5
```

```
> Create trigger Discount_ai
> AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> UPDATE Orders
> WHERE Customer.reg_date <= "2016-01-01" THEN
> SET Total_Price = Total_price - (Total_Price * 0.05) && Discount = 5
>     -> ;
> END$
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Customer.reg_date <= "2016-01-01" THEN
```

```
> Create Trigger Discount_ai
> AFTER INSERT on Orders
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> UPDATE Orders
> Where Customer.reg_date <= "2016-01-01" THEN
> SET Total_Price = Total_Price - (Total_Price * 0.05) && Discount = 5;
> END$
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'Where Customer.reg_date <= "2016-01-01" THEN
> SET Total_Price = Total_Price - (To' at line 6
```

Also forgive for poor formatting. First time making a post here and I saw something about (''' text here```)

So no clue how this is going to show up. Appreciate all help contributed!

Comment: You cannot action a table which fired the trigger in the trigger, you can adjust NEW. values in a before trigger..

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_orders_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON Orders FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE _Discount INT;
    
    SELECT IF(reg_date + INTERVAL 5 YEAR <= CURRENT_DATE, 5, NULL) INTO _Discount FROM Customers WHERE id = NEW.Customer_Id;
    
    IF _Discount > 0 THEN
        SET NEW.Discount = _Discount;
        SET NEW.Discount_Price = NEW.Total_Price * (NEW.Discount / 100);
        SET NEW.Total_Price = NEW.Total_Price - NEW.Discount_Price;
    END IF;
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

I suggest that you add a separate column (computed perhaps) instead of modifying the Total_Price but the above example should get you started.

Comment: OKay so i just make a new column for the New total_price then? and leave total_price as is? I think I get what you are saying. Also I did NOT expect this to be much more different than what I was already doing. I will give it a swing right now. Cheers!

Comment: I would add it as a computed column as there is no need for the value to be stored when it can be generated on the fly. You should probably move the order items to their own table and keep your Orders table for data which is global to the order.

Comment: Is there no way of making it an AFTER Insert and not BEFORE? If I make It an AFTER Insert would I need an additional table to bypass the AFTER insert error(ERROR 13362 (HY000): Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger)???

Comment: No, as @P.Salmon explained. Why do you want to use an AFTER INSERT trigger?

Comment: Was told to go research on it, part of my studies for school. The question said to use AFTER INSERT trigger for total price and discount with 5% discount for customers with over 5 years. After looking at this, almost everything suggests to use BEFORE INSERT trigger. Some suggestions where made that another table i.e discount table, is needed to perform the triggers on and the inserting will take place on the orders table. Something along that. I wanted to make sure before adding a 3rd table to hoist discounts and not mixed with orders. A 3rd table might resolve what @P.Salmon mentioned. Maybe?

Comment: That explains the slightly odd approach ;-)

Comment: Tell me about it. hahaha